# Is it possible to configure a build flavor based on another one?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

There is a project with two build flavors: "flavorA" and "flavorB". Both, inter alia, use "main" source code and resources.
Now I'd like to configure third flavor "flavorC" that will use flavorA's source code with little modifications (specifically, in MainActivity via inheritance) and its own manifest file.
I've read docs and a lot of answers but couldn't find any solution.

Is it real to do this? Or is there any other way to solve the problem?

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution!
It is enough to specify paths in "sourceSets" section:

```
sourceSets {
    ...
    flavorC.java.srcDirs = ['src/flavorA/java', 'src/flavorC/java']
    flavorC.res.srcDirs = ['src/flavorA/res', 'src/flavorC/res']
    flavorC.assets.srcDirs = ['src/flavorA/assets']
    ...
}
```